# how do I use ClassifiedItemsFilterData for folders in Tridion 2011 CoreService?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm rewriting a .NET backend application so that it uses the Tridion 2011 CoreService.
There's one part where it will get a folder in Tridion that uses a particular keyword.
In the current setup, this is done by calling the method 'GetListClassifiedItems' on the keyword itself, but how am I suppose to do this using the CoreService?

There is a **ClassifiedItemsFilterData** available in the CoreService API, but how do I use it?

I've tried this piece of code:

```
ClassifiedItemsFilterData filter = new ClassifiedItemsFilterData()
{
    ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Folder }
};

XElement list = client.GetListXml("tcm:113-363331-1024", filter);
```

but it will only return the keyword itself, with URI tcm:113-363331-1024, and not the folders that have been classified with it.

If I add the component ItemType to the filter too, I will get all components that have been classified with this keywordk, *but still not that folder*.

How do I get the folder too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run a similar test, I ***do*** get both Folders and Components in my result

```cs
var filter = new ClassifiedItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] {ItemType.Folder};
var transactions = client.GetListXml("tcm:1-134-1024", filter);
Console.WriteLine(transactions.ToString());
```

I added a Keyword field to a Metadata Schema and associate that with the Folder. Is that the same way you did it?

When I remove the item types filter from the code above, I get all Components and Folders classified against that Keyword, but I do **not** get the Keyword itself. These are all exactly how I'd expect a `ClassifiedItemsFilterData` to work, so we really should focus on what is different in your scenario.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the results I got, but I can't. It just seems to be working correct now, in my code also. I must've missed some logical error in my code previously...
Sorry guys, and thanx for your time!

Comment: You're welcome Reinder. It gave me a chance to work with a filter type I hadn't tried yet. And thanks for confirming that it works for you too.